# Alterar função CRON do servidor através do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, linux, servidor

É possível alterar alguma função CRON com o PHP ou qualquer outra linguagem?

Por exemplo, possuo a seguinte função não servidor:

```
30 15 * * 1-5 php /var/www/html/projetos/hist_06.php
```

Nessa aplicação o usuário iria inserir que gostaria que o programa fosse executado as 14:00, então o comando no servidor mudaria para:

```
00 14 * * 1-5 php /var/www/html/projetos/hist_06.php
```

Isso é possível?

Comment: Sim é possível, você pode utitilizar o [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php) (**com muito cuidado**, isso é algo que eu não faria) para executar os comandos do crontab (crontab -e) e gerenciar de acordo com o que cada usuário necessita. Uma pergunta, quem é o seu provedor de cloud? Grande maioria já tem soluções melhores pra isso...

Comment: Trabalho com um servidor interno da empresa, não conseguiria fazer isso de outra forma

Comment: Certo, já tentou com shell_exec? Apenas tome cuidado com o que você passa pra essa função, podem tentar injetar código malicioso no request...Tem alguns tutoriais sobre isso: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível sim.

Crie um script em bash, por exemplo em **/etc/scripts/meu_script** para fazer esse tipo de alteração
exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash

min=$1
hra=$2
dia=$3
mes=$4
semana=$5

# Caso algum dos parâmetro seja nulo, seta a variável com "*"
if [[ -z $min ]]; then
    min='*'
fi
if [[ -z $har ]]; then
    hra='*'
fi
if [[ -z $dia ]]; then
    dia='*'
fi
if [[ -z $mes ]]; then
    mes='*'
fi
if [[ -z $semana ]]; then
    semana='*'
fi
# Gera o arquivo de cron com os parametro que foi passado quando o script foi executado
echo "$min $hra $dia $mes $semana $user $cmd" > /etc/cron.d/meu_cron
# Se foi bem sucedido retorna 0 ou 1
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    /etc/init.d/cron restart
    echo 1
else
    echo 0
fi
```

de permissão de execução e adicione o script no arquivo /etc/sudoers.
Note que vc mesmo sendo root não tera permissão para edita-lo, então antes de edita-lo mude a permissão do arquivo

```
chmod 775 /etc/sudoers
```

Faça a seguinte edição

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
**php ALL = NOPASSWD:/etc/scripts/meus_cript**
```

após terminar de edita-lo, volte para as permissões que o arquivo se encontrava

```
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Agora em seu código **PHP** vc pode chamar seu script **bash** sem se preocupar com segurança ao usar **shell_exec** no **PHP**
Execute o script passando os parâmetros desejados

Exemplo:

```
exec=('/usr/bin/sudo /etc/scripts/meu_script 00 14 * * 1-5 php /var/www/html/projetos/hist_06.php')


cat /etc/cron.d/meu_cron

00 14 * * 1-5 php /var/www/html/projetos/hist_06.php
```